# Sum of diagonal of a multi dimensional array (not same rows and columns)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know what all conditions you need to check for sum of all diagonal elements in a multi dimensional array. I have created a 3x5 array  i.e 3 rows and 5 columns and now i want to sum all the diagonal.s if i==j. The other condition used here is if sum of row and column is 1 less than number of rows. So basically this code would work in a square matrix which would help get sum of reverse diagonal as well. But how to find out in case of  irregular dimensioned matrix

The basic condition i

```
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(i==j||i+j==(a.length-1))
            {
                sum=sum+a[i][j];
            }

        }}
```

Comment: Diagonals are not defined for non square matrix, so you will have to specify what you mean by that.

Comment: oh than seems my definition of the same was wrong. my bad.